# Multisim opamp output oscillates for DC volt if it reaches saturation

Tags: operational-amplifier, multisim

Am trying to learn op-amps using Multisim. In the simulation I set initial condition to zero and set the circuit so the output reaches saturation point but instead its ringing with frequency 374HZ. I don't understand is this how the simulators indicates an error or is my calculation for the output voltage wrong

\$\ V_{3}= 4 - 4e^{500t}\$

[image]

Comment: What do you expect your circuit to actually do?

Comment: Am expecting it to not oscillate cause according to the calculation it should reach the op-amps max negative value. Why is it oscillating ?

Comment: I asked what you expected it to do i.e. what is it's function?

Comment: Nothing am just learning about op-amps and using the simulator while I do the calculations by hand and see if its the right result, I don't understand if I connect a circuit like so in real life will it produce the same output as simulator, or maybe am missing a setting that would fix the simulation

Comment: So, you have a circuit with unknown functionality and you want that explained. Unknown functionality usually equals improper behaviour from sims.

Comment: The unknown is the simulators behavior the functionality is calculated accordingly its not my fault that the sim sees 1+1 = cos(wt). so no experimenting only defined circuits that function per design/specification or the sim will lose it...